Springboot / HttpServletResponse is not retreiving the actual HTTP body
I am facing a weird issue on a Spring boot project where the body is not retrievable in the controller.
This is a bit specific: I am using a bc tls psk scheme to talk to sim cards and it has been working without fault for a few years, but now when exchanging with specific cards / devices the payload sent by the card is not available in my Controller.
I am using Springboot 2.5.15, Java 8, BC jdk8on 1.78.1.
I took tcpdump traces an I do see the payload AF 80 23 11 .. .. 00 00 (sim card talk like this, please dont judge them!).
So I am not able to retrieve that payload even though it is there in both the TCP trace AND the content length header tell me it is there.
Here is the TCPDUMP screenshot:

My controller:
public void anyRequest(@RequestHeader(value = CONTENT_TYPE, required = false) String requestContentType,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_PROTOCOL) String adminProtocol,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_FROM) String adminFrom,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_RESUME, required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean adminResume,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_SCRIPT_STATUS, required = false) String adminScriptStatus,
            @RequestBody(required = false) byte[] body, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

In there I usually get the body like this:
Long contentLength = request.getContentLengthLong();
log.info("Request Content lenght in header: {}", contentLength);
if (body != null) {
    log.info("body content {} ", Hex.encodeHexString(body));
            }

And again it works 99 % of the time. But when I use a specific device, it doesnt, body stays null.
I even tried to get it in a few other ways, but with no luck
Try number 1:
if (body == null && contentLength > 0) {

    log.warn("Body seems null while Content length Header is {} ", contentLength);
    log.info("Trying alternative way to retreive the body {} ", contentLength);
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
    body = buffer.toByteArray();
}

Try number 2: (this is actually return a byte array of zeroes, but it was worth trying)
private byte[] alternateBodybytes(InputStream serveltInputStream, int contentLength) throws IOException {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[contentLength];
        for (int r, offset = 0; (r = serveltInputStream.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) > -1;) {
            offset += r;
        }
        
        return bytes;

    }

I am running out of Options at the moment and am looking for suggestions if you guys have any?

Is there another way to get the raw payload maybe at a lower level of the stack within the Springboot framework ?
I hope not to have to update Spring / Java as it would make me have a lot more of regression to do, but it might time.

What do you think? Any advice?
Note: Below is the TCP traces of a transaction where I was able to get the body from @RequestBody(required = false) byte[] body, to me it seems exactly the same, right?


Did you try reading the request using StreamUtils ? something like this :
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
byte[] body = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(is);

Did you try to just fetch all headers into a map instead of requiring some of them? With @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers as parameter.

The contents of the body are exactly the same, so I would focus on other parts of the message. A difference that I saw in the tcpdumps is that the TCP layer of the first dump contains 200 bytes more than the second dump. Maybe some encryption standard is used that you don't support in Java? You didn't show that information in both dumps.

And btw: it's useless to anonymize information in the decoded part, when that information is still visible in the hexdump ;-)

Oops ! thank s for pointing it out, I edited my screenshots, and might have seen a difference between the flows in doing so, I ll check that and the other comment and will let you know. In any case, thatnks !

Spring doesn't do anything to your request/response that is all handled by the servlet container you are using. Is it 1 device, type of device or what is leading to this? I would enable debug logging for the servlet container which probably drops things. That being said also make sure you aren't reading the body somewhere else, as you can only consume the body once.

Also interesting to see that you think it is your code, it is according to you only happening with 1 specific device, while all others work. Maybe a strange suggestion but could it be the device sending the wrong things...

I am gettgin more and more sure this is somehting weird with the device I am connecting with, but I prefer to tell what the issue is exactly, as it usually has more weight than "the error is on your side, please figure it out". But I might end up doing just that.

I tried Both Steam Utils and ContentCachingRequestWrapper and I have the same issue...

Comments suggested that I use StreamUtils and / or ContentCachingRequestWrapper to make sure my body is not already consumed. I used both in sequence and I am still not seeing the required content.
public void anyRequest(@RequestHeader(value = CONTENT_TYPE, required = false) String requestContentType,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_PROTOCOL) String adminProtocol,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_FROM) String adminFrom,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_RESUME, required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean adminResume,
            @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_X_ADMIN_SCRIPT_STATUS, required = false) String adminScriptStatus,
            @RequestBody(required = false) byte[] body, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;

[...]

if (body == null && contentLength > 0) {
            
            log.warn("Body seems null while Content length Header is {} ", contentLength);
            log.info("Trying alternative way #1 to retreive the body using requestWrapper");
            
            byte[] requestPayload = requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            
            if (requestPayload != null && requestPayload.length > 0) {
                log.info("Managed to retreive a body of length {} ", requestPayload.length);
                log.info("alternative body content {} ", Hex.encodeHexString(requestPayload));
                body = requestPayload;
            } else {
                log.warn("Couldnt get the content body using Method 1");
                log.warn("Trying alternative way #2 to retreive the body using alternateBodybytes2");
                
                requestPayload = requestPayload = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(requestWrapper.getInputStream());
                if (requestPayload != null) {
                    log.info("Managed to retreive a body of length {} ", requestPayload.length);
                    log.trace("alternative 2 body content {} ", Hex.encodeHexString(requestPayload));
                } else {
                    
                    log.error("Couldnt extract body content");
                }
                
            }
            
            body = requestPayload;
            
        }


Same result with the following logs:
2024-09-30 09:24:56.149  INFO 4165202 --- [https-psk-bc-nio2-9100-exec-25] c.c.RemoteAdministrationServerController : Request Content length in header: 23
2024-09-30 09:24:56.149  WARN 4165202 --- [https-psk-bc-nio2-9100-exec-25] c.c.RemoteAdministrationServerController : Body seems null while Content length Header is 23
2024-09-30 09:24:56.149  INFO 4165202 --- [https-psk-bc-nio2-9100-exec-25] c.c.RemoteAdministrationServerController : Trying alternative way #1 to retreive the body using requestWrapper
2024-09-30 09:24:56.149  WARN 4165202 --- [https-psk-bc-nio2-9100-exec-25] c.c.RemoteAdministrationServerController : Couldnt get the content body using Method 1
2024-09-30 09:24:56.149  WARN 4165202 --- [https-psk-bc-nio2-9100-exec-25] c.c.RemoteAdministrationServerController : Trying alternative way #2 to retreive the body using alternateBodybytes2


@cybertrain
Here are the difference in the TCP layer, it might be because of reassembled packets ? do you see something weird ?
Failed transaction

Successful transaction:

